# Google Cloud Search - db.blobColumns

Tags: google-api, google-search-api

I'm trying to understand the property db.blobColumns in the database connector --- I've got essentially a massive string of 500,000 characters and I want to use db.blobColumns to upload this text. By the inherent name of blob I am assuming that it is expecting a binary large object? If anyone's used this property before for large text files please help me! I'm at a loss with this particular situation.

Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/database-connector#content-fields

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the db.blobColumn field with database blob(binary) content and it works well by extracting text from the file and doing OCR if its an image. But yes, it also accepts text content in the form of database's CLOB type.

I suggest you take a look at the code of database connector [here](https://github.com/google-cloudsearch/database-connector). Main two files that matter here are DatabaseAccess.java and DatabaseRepository.java.

```
private ByteArrayContent createBlobContent(Map<String, Object> allColumnValues)  {
        byte[] bytes;
        Object value = allColumnValues.get(columnManager.getBlobColumn());
        if (value == null) {
          return null;
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
          bytes = ((String) value).getBytes(UTF_8);
        } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
          bytes = (byte[]) value;
        } else {
          throw new InvalidConfigurationException( // allow SDK to send dashboard notification
              "Invalid Blob column type. Column: " + columnManager.getBlobColumn()
              + "; object type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        return new ByteArrayContent(null, bytes);   
}
```

Above code snippet from the DatabaseRepository.java file is responsible for generating the blob content(binary) which is pushed to Cloud Search. The content of Clob and Blob comes to this function in the form of a byte[]. And is pushed as-is to Cloud Search.

Note from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/limits):

> Google Cloud Search will only index first 10 MB of your content
>   regardless of whether its a text file or binary content.